# How to declare sub matrices after using mat2cell?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have 6x6 matrix (`ud`), which I have split into 3x3 small blocks using the below:

```
%Splitting of array 
B = mat2cell(ud, udBlockVectorR, udBlockVectorC);
```

Next, I want to find the median of each sub matrices in `B`.

I tried using this,

```
for i = 1: 1: udNumBlockC
for j = 1: 1: udNumBlockC
%Find the median of each block
udMV = median( B{i, j}, :);   
end
end
```

However, it does not give me the answers I am looking for.

How do I declare the sub matrices, so that I can use them for the above purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up the 6x6 matrix `ud` as follows,

```
>> B = mat2cell(ud, [3 3],[3 3])
B = 
    [3x3 double]    [3x3 double]
    [3x3 double]    [3x3 double]
```

Next, to get a single value from median for a 2D array, you need to reshape the input (i.e. 3x3 -> 9x1), otherwise you get a value for each column. Horizontally concatenate each sub-matrix so you can reshape them all at once (i.e. 3x12 -> 9x4).  For `ud = magic(6)`:

```
>> meds = median(reshape([B{:}],3*3,[]))
meds =
     7    29    23    14
```

In the above command, `[B{:}]` is the 3x12. The `reshape` command puts all the values in each 3x3 matrix as one of 4 columns. Then `median` computes the median for each column (sub-matrix).

The order of sub-matrixes is (row,col): (1,1), (2,1), (1,2), (2,2).

Comment: Alright, thank you:) next, if i want to compare every element in the 3x3 sub matrix, with the median of the sub matrix, how do i call for each element? use for loop?

Comment: @Amilia If the answer does what you asked, please condider accepting it (use the large tick mark). This request (compare each element with the median) was not on the original question. Anyway: yes, use a `for` loop, or use `arrayfun(@(n) B{n}>=meds(n), 1:numel(B))`, which will give you a cell array with the comparison results